# Windows 10からリモートデスクトップでLinuxサーバーへ接続しOracleをインストールしたい

Tags: linux, oracle

表題の件で質問です。

サーバーOS：Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2
RDP用インストールパッケージ：xrdp、tigervnc-server

上記の環境で、ひとまずWindows 10からLinuxサーバーへリモートデスクトップ接続することはできました。
目的はOracle Database 19cをリモート環境からインストールすることです。
サイレントインストールではなく、GUIを使用したい為以下のコマンドを入力しました。

```
export LANG=C
export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=RHEL8.2
./runInstaller
```

結果は以下の通りです。

```
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.

Can't connect to X11 window server using '192.168.x.x:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

リモートデスクトップ環境でOUI、NETCA、DBCAを起動することはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: インストーラはどのように起動していますか？具体的には、リモートデスクトップ接続を経由してLinuxのGUI環境で実行したのか、それともWindowsから別途TeraTerm等のSSH接続を経由して、のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。LinuxのGUI環境です。Windows 10の「リモートデスクトップ接続」でサーバのデスクトップにアクセスし、サーバの端末を開いて上記コマンドを実行しました。LinuxはVmware Player上に構築した仮想マシンになります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

環境変数 DISPLAY を以下の通り設定してからインストーラを起動してみてください。

```sh
$ export DISPLAY="localhost:0.0"
$ ./runInstaller
```

Comment: rootユーザーにてxhostコマンドを使ってoracleユーザーにX Window Systemへのアクセス権限？を与え、同じくrootユーザーで確認したDISPLAY変数と同じ値をoracleユーザーでも設定することでOUIを起動させることに成功しました（最初oracleユーザーでecho $DISPLAYしたときは空っぽでした）。しかし、今度は起動したOUIが真っ白です。具体的にはうっすらと文字が見えるのですが、とても読めたものではありません。これはWindows側の設定が必要でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10のリモートデスクトップ接続の設定で、True Colorを選択したところ、まともに表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございました。